# How to access TomEE integrated ActiveMQ "Classic" web console

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I am currently working on migrating my EJB app from TomEE 1.7 to TomEE 9. TomEE 9 comes with a integrated ActiveMQ "Classic" ([Integrated TomEE ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/tomee)). I have an MDB named `TransactionManagerBean`.  In the TomEE log I can see that the broker is deployed the MDB (see below) without any issue. So I sent some messages to the queue.  I can see that there are data in the KahaDB (meaning `db.data` has 104KB of data, see image below). But even though there is data in the queue I am not seeing the MDB's `onMessage` method being called.  I tried to access the broker's web console (http://localhost:8161/admin) and get the standard site cannot be reached error. Does anyone know how I can access this TomEE integrated broker web console?

KahaDB directory screen shot:
[image]

TomEE log:

```
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker start
INFO: Starting
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.geronimo.connector.work.WorkerContext run
INFO: Removing non-required WorkContextHandler with no context: org.apache.geronimo.connector.work.TransactionContextHandler@30a7387c
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.geronimo.connector.work.WorkerContext run
INFO: Removing non-required WorkContextHandler with no context: org.apache.openejb.core.security.SecurityContextHandler@3e60d018
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.geronimo.connector.work.WorkerContext run
INFO: Removing non-required WorkContextHandler with no context: org.apache.geronimo.connector.work.HintsContextHandler@3a5f530c
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker$1 run
INFO: Establishing connection to broker [vm://localhost:61616?create=false]
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer$MdbActivationContext start
INFO: Activated endpoint for TransactionManagerBean
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer addJMxControl
INFO: Deployed MDB control for TransactionManagerBean on default:J2EEServer=openejb,J2EEApplication=<empty>,EJBModule=file_/C_/sandboxEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Boss/,StatelessSessionBean=TransactionManagerBean,j2eeType=control,name=TransactionManagerBean
Aug 23, 2023 11:27:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=TransactionManagerBean, ejb-name=Transaction
```